# How to read a line of numbers in php with fscanf

Tags: php, stdin

I am using input from STDIN

A first line is a number that I store in $t

```
fscanf(STDIN, "%s\n", $t);
```

The second line is two integers

I don't know how to store them in an array.

If I do

```
fscanf(STDIN, "%s\n", $n[]);
```

I get an array with just the first value.
I don't know what I am doing here, thank you

Comment: do you know in advance how many numbers there are in any given line? fscanf is for scalars in any case, so to read two values, you have to do `fscanf(STDIN, "%d %d\n", $n[0], $n[1]);` - if the values are separated by space.

Comment: @Jakumi yes, I know how many values there will be. Thank you for your answer. Can you tell me what %d means, how is this working, I do not understand it

Comment: at https://php.net/sprintf the format parameter of https://php.net/fscanf is described. it says "I expect a number here", `%s` is any alphanumeric* sequence. fscanf essentially looks how many placeholders you got and will try to fill the given arguments accordingly. so if you expect two numbers, you have to tell fscanf there are two, and provide two parameters to store them. essentially: read the docs. ;o/ also, the second way of usage is probably much easier ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's probably easier to

```
$n = fscanf(STDIN, "%d %d\n");
```

see examples at https://php.net/fscanf (description of parameters at https://php.net/sprintf)

`$n` will be an array then. if you need separate values, either use the standard syntax `fscanf(STDIN, "%d %d\n", $value1, $value2)` or use the `list` syntax: `list($value1, $value2) = fscanf(STDIN, "%d %d\n")`

I would prefer the return values, because it seems semantically more intuitive, but it's probably just a preference / taste.

Comment: If I need 100 items in an array then I need to use 100 times `%d` in `fscanf` function ?

Comment: essentially, yes. there are probably ways to write that easier with str_repeat, or you could call fscanf 100x and pay attention to line breaks and spaces when doing so, but in the end you either have a scan with 100 `%d` oder you have 100 scans with one `%d` (and more logic). I'd probably do `rtrim(str_repeat('%d ', 100)) . "\n"` to create the scan string